# when building the Json array just the last object appears in the array

Tags: json, groovy

I am calling a restful service to get the documents in the database as a JSON String. So I have two loops `foaList, otaList` when I am doing the following also working just
with one loop I am getting  the right JSON response:

This code retrieve the right response:

```
def param = new HashMap();
    builder{
        results foaList.collect{
            [
              result:   [   
                                         //Here I have not added all json keys and vlaues as in the second case.
                          name: it.getFlexiObject().getByString("name"),
                          version: it.getFlexiObject().getByString("version"),
                      author: it.getFlexiObject().getByString("author")
                 ] 
            ]
        }       
    }
```

Json String with one foaList loop:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "result": {
                "name": "Benzin consume",
                "version": "09.55.00",
                "author": "Alex"
            }
        },
        {
            "result": {
                "name": "Jaspersoft Ultimate guide",
                "version": "sdfdsv",
                "author": "sdvdsv"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but when I try to iterate through the both list I am getting JSON String with the same object.

```
def param = new HashMap();
    builder{
        results foaList.collect{
            otaList.eachWithIndex{item, index ->
               param.put(item.getName(), it.getFlexiObject().getByString(item.getName()));
               }
               result:param       
        }       
    }
```

Json String after looping through the two loops:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "content": "",
            "author": "Alex",
            "description": "Test Json",
            "link": "21120",
            "name": "Benzin consume",
            "fileName": "",
            "contentType": "",
            "version": "09.55.00"
        },
        {
            "content": "",
            "author": "Alex",
            "description": "Test Json",
            "link": "21120",
            "name": "Benzin consume",
            "fileName": "",
            "contentType": "",
            "version": "09.55.00"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get the JSON String with the two objects when iterating through the both lists `foaList, otaList`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my param map was outside the first loop:

```
def param = new HashMap();
    builder{
        results foaList.collect{
            def param = new HashMap();
            otaList.eachWithIndex{item, index ->
               param.put(item.getName(),    it.getFlexiObject().getByString(item.getName()));
               }
        }

    }
```

But it should be:

```
builder{
    results foaList.collect{
        def param = new HashMap();
        otaList.eachWithIndex{item, index ->
           param.put(item.getName(), it.getFlexiObject().getByString(item.getName()));
           }

    }

}
```